# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.models.functions.base'

Tags: python, django

when I'm trying to makemigrations, this error is shown:

> from django.db.models.functions.base import Coalesce
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.models.functions.base'

what shall I do?
I'm using django v.2.2

Comment: Do you use a virtualenv?

Comment: Can you post your full error traceback?

Comment: `from django.db.models.functions.base import Coalesce` can you tell where this import is being made?

Comment: For what it's worth: `.base` existed in Django 2.0, but not in 2.1 or 2.2. Somewhere, somehow, you have mixed up versions of Django.

Comment: If I have to guess, your migration files are from Django 2.0, but you're using 2.2 to migrate them. Check the individual migration files for this particular import statement (see also Sanip's comment).

Comment: it is activated

Answer (score 1):

Your error suggests that you are trying to import `Coalesce` somewhere in your project. As per the documentation of [Django v.2.2 coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce), it needs to be imported as:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
```

Rather than:

```
from django.db.models.functions.base import Coalesce
```